# How do I switch between two SQL connections in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

Since yesterday I have connections to two different SQL Servers in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). One is a SQL Server (called "DS") and the other is to our development environment which is SQL Server Express (called "AS"). Now VSCode seems to have locked on DBDS08 and I don't know how to change it so I'll run my SQL queries against AS. I don't the servers are linked.

Does anyone know how I should do to change between these SQL connections in VSCode?

The VSCode version I'm using is 1.59.0.
The SQL packages installed is:

- SQL Server (mssql), version 1.13.0
- SQL Database Projects, version 0.14.1

Due to security reasons VSCode is run from an environment that is without internet connection.

Comment: I rarely use VS Code for SQL Server (I tend to use ADS), but you can click the server name in the bottom name in the bottom right, disconnect, and then connect to the other instance. If there's a quicker way to change your connection to a different instance, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

@Larnu is correct. On the bottom right, select the server path. A few seconds later the command panel extends with actions to take. Select disconnect. You will see a confirmation in the same place, select yes. To connect to another server select the Text Disconnected on the bottom right and in the command are select the server you want to connect to.